# Windows Forms Application unable to play video [VLC ActiveX Plugin and IE Web Plugin v2]

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, plugins, vlc

My Windows Fomrs Application (Visual C++ - VS 2012) can't play video via *VLC ActiveX Plugin and IE Web Plugin v2*.

During VLC installation (Windows), I selected ActiveX controls, then I selected *VLC ActiveX Plugin and IE Web Plugin v2* from COM Components on VS and I added it on the Form. I typed the full path of the video I want to play on Properties: MRL, but it is not responding when application runs.

Any help for what I am missing, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I typed the full path of the video I want to play on Properties: MRL

Newer versions of VLC require "file///" in the beginning of the path.

(e.g. file///C:\Users...)

Answer (score 1):

Playing a local file works only if its path is preceded by "file:///", not otherwise. Discovered this after much fight. Here is the C# code:

```
string f = @"file:///D:\abc.mp4";
string f2 = @"file:///D:\def.avi";
int i = VLCPlayer.playlist.add(f);
int j = VLCPlayer.playlist.add(f2);

VLCPlayer.playlist.playItem(j);  // to play def.avi
//VLCPlayer.playlist.play();  // to play abc.mp4
```